# How can I enable tab completion for import statements in the Python interpreter?

Tags: python, tab-completion

Is there a way to enable tab completion for the `import` statement in python?

Example:

```
$ cd test/
$ ls
mytest.py
$ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 22:59:56) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import my<TAB>
>>> import shuti<TAB>
```

There is no tab completion for `mytest` or for any other module (eg. `shutil`). I get the same result with python 3.4. I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and my shell is bash.

Note that tab completion does work within other python interpreter contexts, like completing function and identifier names.

I have my .pystartup configured like so:

```
import atexit
import os
import readline
import rlcompleter

readline.parse_and_bind("tab: complete")

historyPath = os.path.expanduser("~/.pyhistory")

def save_history(historyPath=historyPath):
    import readline
    readline.write_history_file(historyPath)

if os.path.exists(historyPath):
    readline.read_history_file(historyPath)

atexit.register(save_history)
del os, atexit, readline, rlcompleter, save_history, historyPath
```

Comment: I would suggest trying out `bpython` via `pip install bpython` then launch bpython as the interpreter wrapper.  It gives tab completion, code hints, and code coloring.

Comment: You should try [IPython](http://ipython.org/) shell.

Answer (score 0):

Default Python's REPL is unable to do that. The only (practical) way to do it now is using IPython (== REPL on steroids and with rocket engine): http://ipython.org/